# Count records which fulfil given condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following schema:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                   table_counter                       |
+----+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| id |      timestamp      | entry_type |    country    |
+----+---------------------+------------+---------------+
+----+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| 10 | 2017-05-01 12:00:00 |    click   |    Germany    |
+----+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| 11 | 2017-05-01 12:00:00 |    view    |    Austria    |
+----+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| 12 | 2017-05-01 12:00:00 |    click   |       UK      |
+----+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| 13 | 2017-05-01 12:00:00 |    view    |      USA      |
+----+---------------------+------------+---------------+
```

I need to return the following result: Select the sum of views and clicks of the top 5 countries by sum of views in the past 30 days.

I know how to count the records all right, but how do I define the constrains? How do I return all entries from five countries with the highest number of `view`s?

Limiting the result to the last 30 days is trivial, but I'm pretty much stuck at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using order by and limit keywords,

```
SELECT SUM(IF(entry_type = "view", 1, 0)) as view_count FROM t3 GROUP BY country, entry_type ORDER BY view_count DESC LIMIT 5
```

**--EDIT**

As per the requirement stated in the comments, here's the updated query:

```
SELECT SUM(view_click_count) as all_total FROM (SELECT country, SUM(IF(entry_type = "view", 1, 0)) as view_count, SUM(IF(entry_type = "click", 1, 0)) as click_count, count(entry_type) as view_click_count FROM t3 GROUP BY country ORDER BY view_count DESC LIMIT 5) t2
```

`all_total` gives the total count as needed, for top 5 countries.

Comment: When I run this query I get the following error message: `#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_name.table_counter.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Changed the query. Try now.

Comment: Thanks gaganshera. This only returns a list of top five view counts. What I need is to find top five countries by view, and then sum up all their views and clicks.

Comment: Also added the country column in the query to show which country the row is.

Comment: This looks awesome. But I do not need to return multiple records. I only need one single number which is a sum of all the entries in the `view_click_count` column...

Comment: Oh I see. Just wrap this up in a query. I'll update the answer to show you how.

Comment: gaganshera this is perfect. You're a star, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get top 5 countries by views with the following query, e.g.:

```
SELECT country, count(*) as 'views'
FROM table
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()
AND entry_type = 'view'
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Now, to select `clicks`, you can add another query in SELECT , e.g.:

```
SELECT t.country, COUNT(*) as 'views',
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM `table`
 WHERE country = t.country
 AND entry_type = 'click'
 AND timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()
) as 'clicks'
FROM `table` t
WHERE t.timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()
AND t.entry_type = 'view'
GROUP BY t.country
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50b678/1/0)**.

**Update**

To get the SUM of views and clicks, wrap the above query into another `SELECT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT country, views + clicks
FROM(
  SELECT t.country, COUNT(*) as 'views',
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM `table`
     WHERE country = t.country
     AND entry_type = 'click'
     AND timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()
    ) as 'clicks'
    FROM `table` t
    WHERE t.timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()
    AND t.entry_type = 'view'
    GROUP BY t.country
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
    LIMIT 5
  ) b;
```

Here's the updated **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50b678/5/0)**.

Comment: Darshan I'm getting the following error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as 'views', a.clicks
FROM counter t, (SELECT COUNT(*) as 'clicks' FROM ta' at line 1`

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ updated the answer with SQL Fiddle. Check now?

Comment: Darshan, it seems to be working now, thanks a lot. However this query is returning a list of top 5 countries with their respective views and clicks individually. What I need is to sum all views and all clicks from these five countries. How do I do that now?

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ added another query (and fiddle), this should do it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
select 
    tc.country,
    count(case entry_type when 'click' then 1 else null end) clicks,  
    count(case entry_type when 'view' then 1 else null end) views
from table_counter tc
inner join (
    select top 5 country from [dbo].[table_counter]
    where entry_type = 'view'
    and timestamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
    group by country
    order by count(entry_type) desc
) t on t.country = tc.country
where timestamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
group by tc.country
order by views desc
```

This is for SQL Server. A few tweaks might be needed for MySQL (i.e. 'Limit' instead of 'TOP')